# How to improve the readability of the x labels in a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

*Hi everyone*

*I did a plot bar for a groupy values in pandas, here's the code for it:*

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 Grouped_D = Dataset.groupby('Dept')['Weekly_Sales'].sum()
 Grouped_D.plot.bar()
```

[image]

*As you can see , since we have 99 departments , the labels are overlapping.*
*And so , i was wondering how can i make it more readable?*
*Any suggestion would be much appreciated , thank you all,*

Comment: rotate them by 45 degree

Comment: i did that , but still very ugly to look at .

Comment: You can also try to make the figsize larger, and/or the font smaller

Comment: share us what's your label are and also share us the screenshot of waht you are getting now after chainging the rotation

Comment: Thank's @Pygirl , indeed , that went completely out of my mind , making the figsize larger , makes it (obviously) clearer , thank's again

Answer (score 0):

*As mentioned by @Pygirl in the comment, increasing the figsize , did the trick.*
*Thank's again*